# Sticky notes in a Virtual JDesktop

Tags: java, beginner, swing, memory-optimization

I made a very practical program consisting of a virtual desktop with a right-click pop-up menu that brings up a button to open a 'stikinote.' These 'stikies' are simply little note-windows where text can be written. (Swing designer, Eclipse.)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StickyWindow {

    private JFrame frmStickiwindou;
    static int i = 0;
    static JInternalFrame stickyWindow;
    static JDesktopPane desktopPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                StickyWindow window = new StickyWindow();
                window.frmStickiwindou.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public StickyWindow() {
    initialize();
}
private void initialize() {
    frmStickiwindou = new JFrame();
    frmStickiwindou.setTitle("StickiDeck");
    frmStickiwindou.setBounds(100, 100, 711, 453);
    frmStickiwindou.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    frmStickiwindou.getContentPane().add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    addPopup(desktopPane, popupMenu);

    JButton btnOpenNewWindow = new JButton("Open New Window");
    btnOpenNewWindow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            createSticky();
        }
    });
    popupMenu.add(btnOpenNewWindow);

    JButton btnCloseAll = new JButton("Close All");
    btnCloseAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            i = 0;
            try {
                stickyWindow.dispose();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
    popupMenu.add(btnCloseAll);

    desktopPane.putClientProperty("JDesktopPane.dragMode", "outline");


}
public void createSticky(){

    int a = 30; int b = 30;
    i++;
    stickyWindow = new JInternalFrame("Sticky (" + i + ")");
    stickyWindow.setVisible(true);
    stickyWindow.setResizable(true);
    stickyWindow.setBounds(300, 75, 300, 225);
    stickyWindow.setMaximizable(true);
    stickyWindow.setClosable(true);
    stickyWindow.setLocation(30, 50); //setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
    desktopPane.add(stickyWindow);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    stickyWindow.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(editorPane);
    stickyWindow.setVisible(true);

    try {
        stickyWindow.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
    component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                showMenu(e);
            }
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                showMenu(e);
            }
        }
        private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

    });

}
}
```

I realized that with just ~6 stiki-windows open, I reach up to about 50MB to 120MB used. Now, isn't that a little too much for just some bare Internal Frames with Text Areas in them? Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: There isn't much **here**, how much more efficient do you expect is possible?

Comment: Did you have a specific question about your program?  Or were you wanting someone to type out a lecture on best practices in general?

Comment: Alright. I'll look there instead, thanks for the help.

Comment: Your nick doesn't let you shine in your best light :-P

Comment: Yep. It's a leftover username from my "gamer" days.